# Android Google map signed Api key issue, map not loading in my app?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my app im using Google maps API so i have generated API key for maps in Google and when I generated a key using eclipse export the Google map is not working in my app before it is working fine, now it showing Gray background . So please help to solve this Issues .

Comment: Is internet Ok? Is your App signed with debugger key or Market certificate?

Comment: yes i checked the internet and also on different devices but it is showing gray background on mapview

Comment: What about key which you are using to sign the apk. Are you simply running it without exporting Signed Apk?

Comment: You might be using wrong key(Map)-key(Apk) combination.

Comment: Did you used your system's hash-code generated Md5 to get key from google?

Comment: yes i generated a key using Md5 to get key from Google im using that key only as it is working fine before when im testing it but im ready to release the app show i export the app through eclipse and i generate key file that all the map is not working in my app....

Comment: There you go. You need to set different map key when you are exporting signed Apk (market ready). You need to get a new MAP KEY against your application key and when you'll download your app from google play it will work fine. I had same issue.

Comment: Ok i will try once by creating a new api key for signed apk .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to generate a new with your new keystore from which you are signing the APK

Comment: How to generate the new API key using the Key that i generated using eclipse .....

Comment: for debug purpose you have to use your android debug.keystore but for production you have your own .keystore file, go to the android docs to "how to generate map api key"

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have added PERMISSION of INTERNET in your Android Manifest File.

Answer (score 0):

once clean and Uninstall old then install new one and then try.
and PERMISSION of INTERNET in your Android Manifest File.

Comment: I have give internet permissions actually its working fine before key file generation in eclipse using export option.